# Android system screen brightness

Tags: android, screen, brightness

I'm developing application that turn on screen (if it has been disabled) and changes screen brightness to 255. Everything works fine. Brightness of Device become maximum. But after little delay, for example 5 second, brightness must return to the previous value. But this value affected only after blocking device not at once, as setting of the maximum value. How can i affect value immediately.

P.S. Sorry for my english.

**Update**

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    float brightnessFloat = 1.0f;
    getOldBrightness();
    setUpNewBrightness(brightnessFloat);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    returnOldBrightness();
}

private void getOldBrightness() {
    try {
        oldBrightness = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
    }
}

private void setUpNewBrightness(float brightness) {
    int brightnessInt = (int) brightness * 255;
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightnessInt);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Old brightness: " + oldBrightness + " ===== New brightness: " + brightnessInt);
    startInvisibleActivity(brightness, false);
}

private void returnOldBrightness() {
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, oldBrightness);
    float brightness = (float) oldBrightness / 255;
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "New brightness: " + brightness);
    startInvisibleActivity(brightness, true);
}

private void startInvisibleActivity(float brightness, boolean screenUnlocked) {
    Intent invisibleActivityIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), InvisibleActivity.class);
    invisibleActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    invisibleActivityIntent.putExtra(BRIGHTNESS_VALUE, brightness);
    invisibleActivityIntent.putExtra(SCREEN_UNLOCKED, screenUnlocked);
    startActivity(invisibleActivityIntent);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that your code immediately makes the display its maximum brightness, but when you try to return it to its previous value, that is delayed?  How do you wait to return the brightness?  Can you post your code?

Comment: In activity there changed WindowManager.LayoutParams screen brightness, and then finish activity after little delay. Worse of all, that this code works correctly if starting when screen is unlocked and enabled.